# REST API endpoint url

Tags: rest

In my application I have `Criterion` and `CriterionGroup` objects.

I have to implement two different REST API endpoints:

1. for getting list of `Criterion` by `CriterionGroup` id
2. for getting `CriterionGroup` itself by id

Right now I use following path in order to GET `CriterionGroup` by id

```
GET /criteria/groups/{criterionGroupId}
```

What path should be used for getting list of criteria by `CriterionGroup` id ?

Comment: you can use `criteriongroups/{criterionGroupId}/criterions` for 1 and `criteriongroups/{criterionGroupId}` for 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting list of `Criterion` by `CriterionGroup` id

```
criteriongroups/{criterionGroupId}/criterions
```

for getting `CriterionGroup` itself by id

```
criteriongroups/{criterionGroupId}
```